# Batch file failing through SQL Server Agent

Tags: ssis, batch-file, sql-agent-job

all.

I wrote an SSIS package that queries data from defined databases and puts them into CSV files in a specific location. Then, within the SSIS package, I call a pre-written batch file that creates a folder in the specified directory, renames the folder to the date in format "yyyy-mm-dd", and then move the created CSV files into the newly created folder.

Batch file code as follows:

```
@echo off
FOR /F "TOKENS=1* DELIMS= " %%A IN ('DATE/T') DO SET CDATE=%%B
FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2 eol=/ DELIMS=/ " %%A IN ('DATE/T') DO SET mm=%%B
FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2 DELIMS=/ eol=/" %%A IN ('echo %CDATE%') DO SET dd=%%B
FOR /F "TOKENS=2,3 DELIMS=/ " %%A IN ('echo %CDATE%') DO SET yyyy=%%B
SET date=%date:~6,6%-%date:~3,2%-%date:~0,2%
md \\remote_folder\%date%
move /Y \\remote_folder\*.csv \\remote_folder\%date%
exit
```

When running this from my SSIS package, everything works fine.

The service account that fires the agent jobs has full administrative control. When scheduling this as an automated job using the SQL Server Agent, the folder doesn't get created properly. My thinking is that the SQL Agent either has trouble firing the batch file, or that they are incompatible.

Has anyone else come across this or know of a work-around?

Comment: Is the batch file being found?

Comment: Yes, but the batch file creates the folder incorrectly when run through the agent. When i say "incorrectly" I mean that the folder is created lets say labeled "12", then it creates a sub-folder labelled "09" and then it creates another sub-folder within the previously created sub-folder labelled "18"

Comment: And what did you mean the folder to be named?  I'm not that great at windows batch scripts.  As another option, you could do this in powershell ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use File System Tasks:

Create a variable called RmtArchPath (string)

Set its value with the expression:

> "\\\\Remote_folder\\" + (DT_WSTR,4)YEAR(GETDATE()) + "-"
>       + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)MONTH(GETDATE()), 2) + "-"
>       + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DAY( GETDATE()), 2)
>       + "\\"

Create a file system task. For operation choose Create Directory. For UseDirectoryIfExists choose True. For IsSourcePathVariable choose RmtArchPath.

Create a second Variable called SrcFileName (string)

Create a ForEachLoop Container.  For Collection choose the enumerator "Foreach File Enumerator", set the Folder = \\Remote_Folder, set the files = *.csv.  For Variable Mappings set the variable = User::SrcFileName.

Connect the File system task to the loop. (from the FS task to the loop for your flow direction).

Create a second file system task inside the loop.

Choose Move file for the operation. Set IsDestinationPathVariable to True, Set DestinationVariable = RmtArchPath. Set IsSourcePathVariable = True, Set SourceVariable = SrcFileName.